# Boost Combination with networking and shared memory for Inter Process Communication

Tags: c++, networking, boost, interprocess, boost-interprocess

This seems like a trivial question for me, but I could not find the answer for it..
I am trying to think of a module of master and multiple slaves (Sends all of them data and receives from all of them results), and I've been looking to some IPC methods,
I see that Named Pipes select the communication channel for me(if the process is on the same computer or not),

But boost seems to refer me to interprocess, if I want shared_memory, or asio, if I want network communication, but I want both! and I want it to select it automatically for me (in Named Pipes manner).

Does anyone know if boost supports such an operation?

Thanks,
Alon

Comment: You could make the actually opened socket different based on this (e.g. a unix-socket if local, an ip-socket if not). Please also note that most unix platforms significantly optimize ip traffic to local host, it won't even hit most of the network processing code, so you might be doing premature optimization here.

Comment: So it will be as fast as shared memory?

Comment: I didn't say that (it likely is a bit slower), always measure to exactly know, but depending on your application (of which you mention nothing) it might be that the difference is negligible.